# How can we render highchart in .net api server side (e.g. Same way we could do with Node js)

Tags: highcharts, server-side-rendering

I cant seem to find a way to render highcharts in asp.net web api. We dont want to host or run a node js server.

Comment: Have you seen the article how to setting own export server in node js? https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.